# Spring Boot - What's it got to do with microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

Pardon my ignorance, but SpringBoot as far as I understand is an aid to set up a spring project.It simplifies dependency management by its opinionated view and takes away the pain associated with gathering all the dependencies on our own.
This apart it has a twist in the way it packages things up i.e it packages the container itself with my app(uber jar) and makes war deployment etc a thing of the past.This kind of blurs the line between a web-app and a non web-app in my opinion.

From my understanding none of this is remotely related to micro-services but often I come across articles sounding like "microservices with SpringBoot". SpringBoot and microservices are used in the same breath giving one the notion that it is Spring's way of building in a microservices way?Isn't this wrong or am I missing something here?

Comment: I want to mention that you can use spring-boot while continuing to package as a `war`  See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Answer (score 0):

First of all, spring boot is a great project. Spring boot use default config but no longer mass of config files. This feature is support by `auto-config` project. And, spring boot use embedded containers, so that you can just start up a service single. That is your self config container such tomcat\jetty is no longer needed. Finally, microservices is just a concept of a service, you can split you service in any way. i.e. every controller class as a microservices is fine, every module as a microservice is fine. For me, use spring boot to build a microservice is a way to quick deploy a service at any service enveriment, I can start a service just copy a jar to a new service, and, run it just use `java -jar`